# Broadcast receiver is not working when ram is clear by user

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

### Hello Coders :) I am new in android development and working with Broadcast receiver it works fine till the ram is not cleared by the user. If user clean a ram all the alarms which i scheduled is getting cleared(not working) :(

Here is my sample code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    String strAction = "com.scheduler.action.WIFI_OFF";
    intent.setAction(strAction);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            022, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm_off.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: After clearing the RAM, if you immediately open your app manually, do your alarms still work?

Comment: No i have to setup alarm once again :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

START_REDELIVER_INTENT -
 It let the OS know about which operation should have to operate continueously.
 It will tell the system to restart and regain the service after the crash and also redeliver the intents that were present at the time of crash happened.